# Joomla! Contact form inside an article, can't get action php file working

Tags: php, joomla, contact-form

I'm trying to create a contact form on my own. I noticed that it can be achieved by placing the form inside an article, instead of a custom html module.

In the client side, it seems to work. I even added a captcha manually (the re-captcha plugin doesn't seem to work for me). The problem is, I set form's action property as "mail.php", and just added this "mail.php" file to the the template root. The "mail.php" supossedly retrieves the data send by post, and finally composes and sends the email, showing a "message send" notification.

Anyway, when I click on submit, the form page is just reloaded. I guess that Joomla! can't find my "mail.php". I guess that this issue is related to the joomla structure and my inability to place the "mail.php". Any help will be wellcome.

This is how my article looks like (wysiwyg editor mode disabled):

```
<form action="mail.php" method="post" target="_blank">
<p><label for="nombre">Nombre:</label></p>
<p><input maxlength="50" name="nombre" size="30" type="text" /></p>
<p><label for="email">Email:</label></p>
<p><input maxlength="50" name="email" required="required" size="30" type="text" /></p>
<p><label for="asunto">Asunto:</label></p>
<p><input maxlength="150" name="asunto" size="30" type="text" /></p>
<p><label for="mensaje">Mensaje:</label></p>
<p><textarea cols="50" maxlength="700" name="mensaje" required="required" rows="8"></textarea></p>
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6Lefblahblahblahblah"> </div>
<p><input type="submit" /></p>
</form>
```

Comment: Is there a site where I could check your problem?

Comment: Why not use the Joomla mail api? What do you mean by the recaptcha plugin doesn't work? How are you trying to use it? I would use the full path to reference a file, how is this form supposed to know where to find it? The template root is the last place to look for a library type file.

Comment: Yep, the recaptcha plugin doesn't work. I enabled it in the plugin list and also in global configuration. I added the public and private key. Still, it doesn't appear in my form. The only way to have a captcha working is adding the code that googles provides, that is a <script> in the header of the index.php: `<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>` and a <div> in the place where I need the captcha (just above the submit button):  `<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="213thekey"></div>` Anyway, it is working. As for the .php location, I'm struggling with it.

Comment: Is your code triggering the needed events for the plugin? it doesn't magically know that you have created a form and inserted it in an article. Did you also enable it in global configuration?